# Google analytics ecommerce status code 200 OK but transactions are not showing

Tags: server-side, google-analytics-api

For several reasons i don't want to use the Google Analytics javascript code for my transactions but a server-side solution. I've made a C# function that makes a web request to the Google servers.

When a make a request for a transaction I get the following:

```
responseUri: http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?
                                        utmwv=5.3.7
                                        &utms=1
                                        &utmn=7470436714
                                        &utmhn=www.fotofabriek.nl
                                        &utmsr1680x1050
                                        &utmvp=1680x1050
                                        &utmsc=32-bit
                                        &utmul=nl-NL
                                        &utmje=0
                                        &utmfl=11.5%r31
                                        &utmhid=4470327307
                                        &utmr=test
                                        &utmp=Winkelwagen
                                        &utmt=item&utmtid=7854
                                        &utmipc=fb0115
                                        &utmipn=Visitekaartjes
                                        &utmipr=12.97
                                        &utmiqt=3
                                        &utmiva=Visitekaartjes
                                        &utmac=UA-13256617-1

statucode: OK

responseUri: http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?
                                        utmwv=5.3.7
                                        &utms=0
                                        &utmn=1271427811
                                        &utmhn=www.fotofabriek.nl
                                        &utmsr1680x1050
                                        &utmvp=1680x1050
                                        &utmsc=32-bit
                                        &utmul=nl-NL
                                        &utmje=0
                                        &utmfl=11.5%r31
                                        &utmhid=0621675512
                                        &utmr=test
                                        &utmp=Winkelwagen
                                        &utmt=tran
                                        &utmtci=Groningen
                                        &utmtco=NL
                                        &utmtrg=
                                        &utmtid=7854
                                        &utmtst=fotofabriek
                                        &utmtsp=2.35
                                        &utmtto=27.64
                                        &utmttx=4.80
                                        &utmac=UA-13256617-1

statucode: OK
```

What is going wrong here? The above are the requests made to the servers with te corresponding statuscodes. I am getting a statuscode 200 OK but in Analytics Ecommerce my transactions are not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mean time i've trying and trying and trying. And then i found the solution.
I missed some parameters for the cookiestring.

I've made a C# wrapper for this which will be up on codeproject soon. When it is i'll post the link for those of you who could use it.

EDIT: link to the source code http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493455/Server-side-Google-Analytics-Transactions